# how to check if (c#) ControlCollection.Find() has returned a result

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using [ControlCollection.Find()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find.aspx) method in C# to find some picture boxes present in my form.

I am storing the returned result in a Control[] array. How do I find out if the Find() was successful or not???

Code

```
Control[] temp = pictureBoxCollection.Find(TagNo, true);
if(temp.Length>0)
    UpdateRes = update_status(TagNo, Status);
```

where TagNo is a string containing the Control's exact name.

Yes. I'm using the control's exact name. And I have used the Find() method successfully earlier (when the Control was surely present in the Collection). I am having a problem this time because the control may or may not be present in the Collection.

Comment: How can you tell that update_status is not running? Maybe it's running and the problem is there?

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried?

```
var result = controlCollection.Find(contolName,true);
if(result == null || result.Length == 0)
{
   // fail to find
}
```

You can use this method to see list of all controls

```
    public void FillControls(List<string> container,Control control)
    {
        foreach (Control child in control.Controls)
        {
            container.Add(child.Name);
            FillControls(container,child);
        }
    }
```

And then use:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        List<string> controls = new List<string>();
        FillControls(controls,this);
    }
```

Comment: I did try this albeit its inverse. But unfortunately result == null is always evaluating to false and result.Count is always evaluating to true.

Comment: `Control[] temp = pictureBoxCollection.Find(TagNo, true);
if(temp.Length>0)
    UpdateRes = update_status(TagNo, Status);`

Comment: are you sure that there is control with name that is in `TagNo`

Comment: I checked the Controls present on the collection while debugging with VS2010 earlier and the pictureBox was present.  I guess I should start over. Probably the fault lies deeper. Thanks Stecya and all.

Answer (score 0):

Safest way will be to check if the returned array is not `null` and has Length of more than 0:

```
Control[] children = this.Find("mypic", true);
if (children != null && children.Length > 0)
{
   //OK to proceed...
}
```

Comment: I tried this exactly but the first exp is always evaluating to true and second to false. Even if the Control is present in the collection.

Comment: @Khemka please edit your original question and show the code you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Find() method will return an empty array (never null) if no controls were found. So you should simply do something like:

```
Control[] controls = myForm.Find("picbox", true);
if (controls.Length > 0) {
   // Do logic when picture boxes are found
} else {
   // Do logic when there are no picture boxes
}
```

Comment: Agreed. Thats why I was having a problem when I used both constraints. But Even now, controls.Length is always evaluating to 0. Even if the pic-box is present in the collection.

Comment: Can you provide an example on how you're using Find()? The _key_ parameter is the control's **exact name**, not text that the name may contain.

Comment: Yes. I'm using the control's exact name. And I have used the Find() method successfully earlier (when the Control was surely present in the Collection). I am having a problem this time because the control may or may not be present in the Collection.

Comment: So you may consider the case that the control **is not present**! Otherwise there is a bug on Find() method, something that I don't really believe

Comment: I don't think the Find() method would be bugged. Maybe the problem in my code lies somewhere else. Thanks anyways. :)

Comment: Yes, I guess that's the case :) @Stecya code snippet is exactly what you want to check which controls lies on the container. Good luck!